# How to read *_LOW_HN / *_HIGH_HN fields in NY Street Centerline Data?

Tags: united-states, address, streets, segment

I've been looking at the [NYC Street Centerline (CSCL)](https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/NYC-Street-Centerline-CSCL-/exjm-f27b), in particular number ranges for individual street segments.

Quite a few look like this:

```
           ST_NAME L_LOW_HN L_HIGH_HN R_LOW_HN R_HIGH_HN
0               28  215-001   215-027  215-000   215-026
1           QUEENS  120-011   120-011        0         0
2               58   51-001    51-099   51-000    51-098
3           FOREST   68-049    68-099   68-050    68-098
4               69  110-001   111-099  110-000   111-098
5              105  107-001   108-099  107-000   108-098
6           BEACON   14-025    14-099   14-024    14-098
7               49  108-001   110-099  108-000   110-098
```

an I have a trouble to wrap my head around these values.

How do I read for example `08-001` or `14-025`? How do these correspond to odd and even numbers?

Can someone explain this on an example?